# Kth Shortest Path

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

Does anyone know how can I write a programming graph-algorithm (C++ code would be great) that finds the Kth shortest path for a given set of nodes and edges in a cyclic graph?

For example, the shortest path (that could be found by Dijkstra or Bellman Ford) is considered to be the 1th shortest path. Now the 2nd shortest path is the shortest one that comes after the 1st shortest path. Now I want the algorithm to find the Kth shortest path.
you are given the number of nodes, edges and the set of edges, as the following:

number of nodes: 5
number of edges: 6
edges:
0 1
0 2
1 2
2 3
3 1
1 4
source node:0
destination node: 4

"Note that this graph contains a cycle"
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [uniform cost search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_cost_search) algorithm. Where the Wikipedia says "return solution", don't quit and `return` but append the result to some list until that list contains *k* paths. The *k*'th element of the list (counting from 1) will be the *k*'th shortest path.

Don't keep a "closed"/"explored" set or this algorithm won't work properly.

Comment: @TravelingSalesman: I said BFS, not DFS. BFS can handle cycles.

Comment: if you mean that i should find every possible path using DFS or BFS then this is not going to work. In my case, the graph contains cycles which will result in a path that will not appear using DFS algorithm.    However, if you mean that I should modify BFS Algorithm then that is what I am looking for and to me, It doesn't seem that easy.

Comment: I'm not saying you should find all paths. BFS can be written in such a way as to only find the shortest path, or the *k* shortest paths. And again, I'm not talking about DFS.

Comment: that's interesting....Can you please give me any code or any link that can be helpful?

Comment: @TravelingSalesman: I linked to the Wikipedia in the answer. Look at the pseudocode there and insert the modification I suggested. It's not very hard.

Comment: thanks alot, if this worked...I will make a party and invite you.

Comment: The OP says for shortest path he needs Bellman Ford or Dijkstra. That suggests **weighted problem**. BFS fails when it comes to weighted graphs.

Comment: @amit: there are no weights in the example graph. If there were I'd have recommended uniform cost search.

Comment: If you assume non-weighted problem, it should be explicitly mentioned in the answer IMO.

Comment: What, you have a weighted graph? Then use UCS as described in the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_cost_search), remove the `explored` set and apply my advice.

Comment: Thank youuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu, if I can vote for you, I would make it 1000 times. But I am just new here

Comment: I did checked it, and I verified that the algorithm works fine with my case. Thanks alot!